# Is it a bad practice to define class options through an array?

Tags: php, class, settings

When we take a look at Javascript frameworks like Dojo, Mootools, jQuery, JS Prototype, etc. we see that options are often defined through an array like this:

```
dosomething('mainsetting',{duration:3,allowothers:true,astring:'hello'});
```

Is it a bad practice to implement the same idea when writing a PHP class?

**An example:**

```
class Hello {

    private $message = '';
    private $person = '';


    public function __construct($options) {

        if(isset($options['message'])) $this->message = $message;
        if(isset($options['person'])) $this->person = $person;
    }


    public function talk() {

        echo $this->person . ' says: ' . $this->message;
    }
}
```

**The regular approach:**

```
class Hello {

    private $message = '';
    private $person = '';


    public function __construct() {}


    public function setmessage($message) {

        $this->message = $message;
    }


    public function setperson($person) {

        $this->person = $person;
    }


    public function talk() {

        echo $this->person . ' says: ' . $this->message;
    }
}
```

The advantage in the first example is that you can pass as much options as you want and the class will only extract those that it needs.

For example, this could be handy when extracting options from a JSON file:

```
$options = json_decode($options);
$hello = new Hello($options);
```

This is how I do this regulary:

```
$options = json_decode($options);
$hello = new Hello();

if(isset($options['message'])) $hello->setmessage($options['message']);
if(isset($options['person'])) $hello->setperson($options['person']);
```

Is there a name for this pattern and do you think this is a bad practice?

*I have left validation etc. in the examples to keep it simple.*

Comment: I do not think so, it is used extensively is Drupal CMS!

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know such a big name is using it.

Comment: IIRC that JS syntax is not felt as an array, but as the "serialized" representation of an object (it's used e.g. in JSON all the time).

Comment: It's called a Unified Constructor: http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/1113

Comment: @scoates: Are you sure? PHP has its own definition for "unified constructors": http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @Matteo: In the code above it is not a "serialized" representation of an object but an object literal. In other words, the object itself. JSON is a different matter entirely, it is simply a string format used to communicate with the server.

Comment: @slebetman: actually I somehow knew it (I used it several times in JS code), but being primary a C++ developer I didn't know that it was called like that; good to know, thank you. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are good and bad aspects.

**The good:**

- No need for multiple method signatures (i.e. overloading, where supported)
- In keeping with the previous point: methods can be invoked with arguments in any order
- Arguments can be dynamically generated, without needing to specify each one that will be present (example: you dynamically create an array of arguments based on user input and pass it to the function)
- No need for "boilerplate" methods like `setName`, `setThis`, `setThat`, etc., although you might still want to include them
- Default values can be defined in the function body, instead of the signature (jQuery uses this pattern a lot. They frequently `$.extend` the options passed to a method with an array of default values. In your case, you would use `array_merge()`)

**The bad:**

- Unless you properly advertise every option, your class might be harder to use because few will know what options are supported
- It's one more step to create an array of arguments when you know ahead of time which you will need to pass
- It's not always obvious to the user that default values exist, unless documentation is provided or they have access to the source code

In my opinion, it's a great technique. My favorite aspect is that you don't need to provide overloaded methods with different signatures, and that the signature isn't set in stone.

Comment: +½ for pointing out the need for proper documentation. +½ for mentioning both advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Great line up of the good and the bad! The project I want to implement this in has good documentation so that one shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with that approach, especially if you have a lot of parameters you need to pass to a constructor. This also allows you to set *default* values for them and `array_merge()` them inside a constructor (kinda like all jQuery plugins do)

```
protected $default_params = array(
    'option1' => 'default_value'
);
public function __construct($params = array()) {
    $this->params = array_merge($this->default_params, $params);
}
```

If you want live examples of this "pattern", check out symfony framework, they use it almost every where: here's [an example of sfValidatorBase constructor](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorBase.class.php#L51)

Answer (score 3):

When you give the arguments names it's called "Named Notation" v.s. "Positional Notation" where the arguments must be in a specific order.

In PHP you can pass an "options" parameter to give the same effect as other languages (like Python) where you can use a genuine Named Notation.  It is not a bad practice, but is often done where there is a good reason to do it (i.e. in your example or a case where there are lots of arguments and they do not all need to set in any particular order).

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this is a hack to get named parameters in languages that don't support them. Not many people know about named parameters in general until they are exposed to this hack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the name, but i really doubt it is a bad practice, since you usally use this when you wan't to declare a small o quick function or class property

Answer (score 1):

If there are mandatory options, they should be in the constructor's parameter list. Then you add the optional options with default values.

```
public function __construc($mandatory1, $mandatory2, $optional1="value", $optional2="value") { }
```

If all of your options are optional, then it can be useful to create a constructor taking an array. It would be easier to create the object than with a "normal constructor" : you could provide just the options you want, while with a "normal constructor" if you want to provide $optional2, you have to provide $optional1 (even setting it to the default value).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say its bad practice, at least if you trust the source of the data.

Another possibility would be dynamically calling the setters according to the options array key, like the following:

```
public function __construct($options) {
    foreach($options as $option => $value) {
        $method = 'set'.$option;
        if(method_exists($this, $method)
            call_user_func(array($this, $method, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do both? Have your constructor *cake and eat it too* with a static factory "named constructor": 

`$newHello = Hello::createFromArray($options);`

You first have your constructor with the options in order. Then add a static method like this to the same class:

```
public static function createFromArray($options){

    $a = isset($options['a']) ? $options['a'] : NULL;
    $b = isset($options['b']) ? $options['b'] : NULL;
    $c = isset($options['c']) ? $options['c'] : NULL;

    return new Hello($a, $b, $c);
}
```

This will keep new developers and IDE's happy as they can still see what it takes to construct your object.

I agree with the general attitude of the answers here in that either way is a viable solution depending on your needs and which is more beneficial for your app.